# ffmpeg video with watermark and subtitle at same time

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, h.264, watermark

Hi I want to add watermark png image to video with hardcode substitle .srt file at same time what changes i should do the to following line

ffmpeg -i input.mkv -threads 0 -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -preset veryslow -vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=0:0 [out]"  output.mp4

Answer (score 2):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i watermark.png -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -preset veryslow -filter_complex overlay;subtitles=subtitle.srt output.mp4
```

- Use `-filter_complex` when your filter involves more than one input. This is called a [complex filtergraph](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Complex-filtergraphs) as opposed to a [simple filtergraph](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Simple-filtergraphs).
- Use of the `movie` multimedia source filter is not required.

Also see:
[Official FFmpeg documentation for `overlay` video filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1)
[Official FFmpeg documentation for `subtitles` video filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1)
[FFmpeg Wiki: How to burn subtitles into the video](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20burn%20subtitles%20into%20the%20video)

Comment: I get this error when i do this command [Parsed_subtitles_1 @ 000000000437d020] No usable fontconfig configuration file
found, using fallback.

Comment: @Qatarson Please update your question with your ffmpeg command and complete ffmpeg console output.

Comment: ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -preset veryslow -filter_complex overlay;subtitles=subtitle.srt output.mp4

Comment: here command output

Comment: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2013-03-26 13:27:16
  Duration: 00:01:55.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1825 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x544,
 1631 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 48k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 19
1 kb/s

Comment: Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-03-26 13:27:17
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Input #1, image2, from 'watermark.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba, 75x63 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 25:21], 25 tbr, 25 t
bn, 25 tbc
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
[Parsed_subtitles_1 @ 00000000046cfdc0] No usable fontconfig configuration file
found, using fallback.
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_subtitl
es_1

Comment: @Qatarson That's not really readable. Please include your complete ffmpeg command and the complete ffmpeg console output. You can add it to your question and not to the comments.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to add dynamic image overlay on live stream video input? Means we can keep changing image overlay after video stream started?

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to @llogan's answer, I had to use a comma (not semicolon)

```
vid=video.mp4
img=ovelay.png
sub=subtitles.srt
out=output.mp4

ffmpeg -i $vid -i $img -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=2:2,subtitles=$sub" $out
```

Result:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBNMxTXUOaM

(p.s. completely unrelated: I'd rather use -c:v libx265, almost half the size)